# Beam/Dataflow: maxTimestamp for topology with no Window defined

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

What is expected behavior of maxTimestamp for a global window?
I have a topology with unbounded source which does not specify windowing strategy. When I access maxTimestamp field of BoundedWindow, I get a timestamp which is in the future. Is this expected behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is intended behaviour. The end of the global window must be somewhat smaller than the max timestamp value what is possible in Beam, often referenced as +infinity in practice.

From the source code of [GlobalWindow.java](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/v2.9.0/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/windowing/GlobalWindow.java):

```
 // Triggers use maxTimestamp to set timers' timestamp. Timers fires when
 // the watermark passes their timestamps. So, the maxTimestamp needs to be
 // smaller than the TIMESTAMP_MAX_VALUE.
 // One standard day is subtracted from TIMESTAMP_MAX_VALUE to make sure
 // the maxTimestamp is smaller than TIMESTAMP_MAX_VALUE even after rounding up
 // to seconds or minutes.
 private static final Instant END_OF_GLOBAL_WINDOW = extractMaxTimestampFromProto();
```